# Check the radio button based on the value fetched from mysql database

Tags: php, html

For my app I need to fetch the data from the database and mark fields accordingly. I am stuck with how to mark the radio button based on the value fetched. I am sharing the code I wrote to fetch the data and the radio button which I need to check.

```
$Medical_Record_Id=$_SESSION['Medical_Record_Id'];
$DOL=$_SESSION['DOL'];
$hour=$_SESSION['hour'];
$Question1="xxx";
$data1 = 'SELECT Option_Selected FROM Form1 WHERE Medical_Record = "'.$Medical_Record_Id.'" and DOL="'.$DOL.'" and hour="'.$hour.'" and Question="'.$Question1.'"' ;
$query = mysql_query($data1) or die("Couldn't execute query. ". mysql_error());
```

The html code which I have for the radio button is

```
 <div>
         <span> 
         <input type="radio" name="Gestational_age"  class="field checkbox" value="<28" tabindex="7" />
         <label class="choice" for="Gestational_age"><28</label>
         </span>
         <span>    
         <input type="radio" name="Gestational_age" class="field checkbox" value="28-31" tabindex="7" />
         <label class="choice" for="Gestational_age">28-31</label>
         </span>
         <span>    
         <input type="radio" name="Gestational_age" class="field checkbox" value=">=32" tabindex="7" />
         <label class="choice" for="Gestational_age">>=32</label>
         </span>
         </div>
```

Please guide me in how to check the radio button based on the value I am fetching in $query .

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your HTML is really messed up. If you want to use symbols such as `>`, `<` in HTML attribute values or as text to display in the labels, you should convert them to the respective HTML entities, e.g., `&lt;`, `&gt;`.

After that, if you need to mark a value as selected, you should use the `checked` attribute on the specific `<input>` control:

```
<input type="radio" checked="checked" .... >
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to show your input checked put some like below, see the second input

```
<form> 
<input type="radio" name="Gestational_age" class="field checkbox" value="<28" tabindex="7">
<input type="radio" name="Gestational_age" class="field checkbox" value="28-31" tabindex="7" checked="checked">
<input type="radio" name="Gestational_age" class="field checkbox" value=">=32" tabindex="7">
</form>
```