# check the radio button based in the output of if condition in php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I searched for the answer everywhere, although similar questions are already there on stackoverflow i did not find a satisfactory answer.

Following are the question i've referred,

[checked the radio button based on the ajax response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48604856/9294927)

[Check the radio button based on the value fetched from mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20183761/9294927)

What i have is data coming in from model in object `$data`.

So i fetch it in my view like $data->is_male.

What i want is `if($data->is_male == 1)` then check the button,

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value=

              <?php if ($data->is_male == 1): ?>
                                    'checked'
              <?php endif ?>> Male<br>

<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
```

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301164/how-to-get-checked-radio-button-in-edit-page-in-php

Comment: thanks i'll try it out and let you know...

Comment: Just wanted to mention you have $data->$data in your example

Comment: You're missing the `value` attribute. I'm assuming you want `value="male"`. And there should be no quotes around `checked`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" 
    <?php if ($data->$data->is_male == 1): ?>
               checked="checked"
    <?php endif ?>> Male<br>

<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is a more readable answer. I have used `PHP` ternary conditional operator here.

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" <?php echo ($data->is_male==1) ? 'checked="checked"':'';?>>Male
<br>

<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female
<br>
```